# Powershell Write-Progress Command in GUI stops right before it is finished

Tags: powershell, user-interface, progress-bar

The Code i use works perfectly fine in standalone, but now that i put it into an button it stops.
for example i have 400571 Lines, in which i look for matches, and the progress bar stops at Line 400000 because i told him to update the write progress every 1000 Lines to improve the performance.

Im pretty sure the critical point has to be if($i % 1000 -eq 0) because if i lower it to 10 he would stop at 400570 and still dont finnishes, but i dont want to set it to 1, because refreshing the progressbar every line takes up much more time.

The Code included in the button is:

```
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,10)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Filtern"
$OKButton.Name = "Filter"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$OKButton.Add_Click({$i= 0
$path = "C:\temp\smtpfilter\LNS5filter.txt"
$length = (Get-Content $path).Length

#Datum, Hostname und Message Nummer
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            #$dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            #$dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            #DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }
        $i++
    if($i % 1000 -eq 0){
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    }
 }}

 #Messages Counted
 $cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        #DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
```

(i # the dns commands because i work remote right now and it would take way to long to resolve the names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach-object` *is* running 400571 times - you just stop updating the progress bar at iteration 400000.

If you update the progress bar again after the foreach-object is finished you'll hit the magic 100% complete...

```
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
 ...
 }}

# final update to progress bar with total items processed
Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)

#Messages Counted
$cumulative = ...
```

**Update**

You'll also need to move the counter logic outside the `if` clause, otherwise you're only counting the number of *matched* records processed...

```
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        ...
        # move these lines out from the "if( $_ -match ..."
        $i++
        if($i % 1000 -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
        }
    }
}
```

becomes

```
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {

    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]')
    {
        ...
    }

    # now we're counting *every* record, not just the ones that match
    $i++
    if( $i % 1000 -eq 0 )
    {
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    }

}

# final update to progress bar with total items processed
Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)

...
```

Comment: Ah, you need to move the counter *after* the ```if($_ -match { ... }```, otherwise you're only counting iterations that match the ```if``` clause.

Comment: wait, could it be that i acnt have 2 sepperated commands in one button?

Comment: @Trippin - see update above. note the indents and where the ```{``` and ```}``` have moved  to compared to your original code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the Progress bar finishes now, but apparently this wasnt the only problem in the script because the $cumulative variable is still empty after it. When i mark them  in ISE and run them without being in a button they work just fine.